# Parse json data with bash

Tags: mysql, jq

I would like to generate some commands accoring to data stored in a field of mysql table.

To get the data and store them in a variable i do the following

```
modules=$(/usr/bin/mysql  -u $MyUSER -p$MyPASS $DB_NAME -e "SELECT modules FROM myapp WHERE ID=31 " -B  -N)
```

In the database the data is stored like in json format :

```
["module-name-1","module-2","https:\/\/domain.com\/module\/packages\/mailmdule.zip"]
```

I want to iterate each element of this list and produce a line with a command that would look like

```
install module-name-1 -yes --no-prompt 
install module-2 -yes --no-prompt 
install https://domain.com/module/packages/mailmdule.zip -yes --no-prompt
```

Please note that the URL in the last command is formatted differently than it in the json

I was looking for a solution through jq but did not succeed, I have tried to get a clean output :

```
$((/usr/bin/mysql  -u $MyUSER -p$MyPASS $DB_NAME -e "SELECT modules FROM myapp WHERE ID=31 " -B  -N)| jq '.[]'))
```

But i only get

```
"module-name-1" "module-2" "https:\/\/domain.com\/module\/packages\/mailmdule.zip"
```

Would appreciate any suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -r '.[] | @sh "install \(.) -yes --no-prompt"'
```

This would take your array and insert the elements, properly quoted for the shell, into a string that is then outputted.

Given the array that you show, this would produce

```
install 'module-name-1' -yes --no-prompt
install 'module-2' -yes --no-prompt
install 'https://domain.com/module/packages/mailmdule.zip' -yes --no-prompt
```

An array element containing single quotes and spaces etc. would be handled correctly.

To run these commands in the shell, pipe them to `sh -s`:

```bsh
jq -r '.[] | @sh "install \(.) -yes --no-prompt"' | sh -s
```

Or, you could just do a shell loop reading the data from the array and using that in the `install` command line rather than trying to construct a valid command in `jq`:

```bsh
jq -r '.[]' |
while IFS= read module; do
    install "$module" -yes --no-prompt
done
```

This obviously won't work if any array element contains an embedded newline.

Comment: I have tried this and it seems to be pretty close to what i am looking for, except that for the output. It is all in one single line. Also the URL is not formatted correctly. I still have this : 
https:\/\/domain.com\/module\/packages\/mailmdule.zip

Comment: @yazzou Ah, you're trying to run it with a command substitution. No, that won't work, obviously. I'm updating the answer, hold on.

Comment: Thanks ! 
just to be complete, and to get rid of the "\/\/" in the module url, i have replaced this   install "$module" -yes --no-prompt

 by this : 
install "${module//\\/}" -yes --no-prompt

Comment: @yazzou I never had to do that with the data that I copied from your question. Are you using `-r` with `jq`?

Comment: Yes i am using it but my output was not as expected